# jQuery - How do I have an accordian li open when I am in a specific path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I have built a simple accordian style menu. It works, but I would like it to have a specific section toggled open when in a path related to that menu. So if I would be in the "Mens" part of the clothing store, the Mens section of the menu with the child

would be visible or toggled. Right now you can click and toggle open each section, but they are all closed when the page first loads. The website section I am referring to is here: http://bemidjisports.designangler.com/men The menu is on the left side.

I assume it has something to do with the jQuery .toggle() method, but I am not sure. Could someone give me an example of this based on the code below?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav_1489829 li.link-header a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings("ul").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#nav_1489829 li.link-header a").click(function(f) {
         var href = this.href;
         window.location = href;
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav_1489829 li.selected").ready(function(g) {
        $("li.selected").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not use `$('li.selected').show();` instead of toggle at first? Also, you don't need multiple `$(document).ready()` functions, they can all go into a single function.

Comment: How would I check the url path so that I can have specific menu items shown? Thank you for your advice so far.

Comment: Something like this?

    `$("li.link-header a").each(function() {
        var a = $(this);
        var href = a.attr('href');
        var url = window.location;
        if( *compare url with href* ) {
            a.siblings("ul").slideToggle("fast");
        }
    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("#nav_1489829 li.selected a").trigger('click');
```

Comment: It works except since I have it inside of a ready function, it will keep opening over and over. Any solution for this? Sorry, still pretty new at javascript and jQuery.

Comment: Try `$("#nav_1489829 li.selected > a")`

Comment: That is a lot closer, now I just need to figure out how to deal with behaviors on my selected classes since it seems to add it only to the first li.